# If $I_n=\int _0^\pi \sec^nx \, dx$, then how to find $I_{10}$+$8\over 9$ $I_8$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $I_n=\int_0^\pi \sec^nx \, dx$, then I have to find $I_{10}$+$8\over 9$$I_8$.

The problem is I know the reduction formula for $\sec^n x$ which is explicitly shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNKLYmlN2M8) but using that I can find $I_{10}$-$8\over 9$$I_8$. Can someone tell me the simplest way to find $I_{10}$+$8\over 9$$I_8$ ?

Comment: You know $I_{10}-8/9I_{8}$, now $I_{10}+8/9I_8=(I_{10}-8/9I_8)+16/9I_8$. Reduce the latter term all the way down. (That's not necessarily the simplest way, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Sanchayan, do you mean to be taking a definite integral over interval $[0,\pi]$? This integral $$I_n=\int_0^\pi \sec^n(x) \, dx$$ doesn't even always converge.  For example, check out the case $n=2$.  Standard calculus 2 techniques will prove my point.

Comment: So what? He's only asking about the cases $n=8$ and $n=10$? ${}\qquad{}$